# Check Internet connection reachability in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin plugin to check internet connection reachability in my xamarin forms mobile application. But it's taking some time to load. Is there any way to reduce the loading time?

```
       if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
       {
           if (await CrossConnectivity.Current.IsRemoteReachable(new Uri("https://www.google.lk/").Authority))
           {
               //do some thing
           }
           else
           {
              //connection is not reachable
           }
       }
```

Comment: Welcome. Please don't post screenshots of code. [ask].  Wishing you well

Comment: It probably loads the whole page in the background to determine if it is reachable, so probably the only way to cut the load time is to choose a lighter website.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the step 2 of the following blog : How to check network status from Xamarin.Forms app?
https://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.in/2017/04/xamarinforms-consuming-rest-webserivce_17.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using Xamarin Essentials Connectivity:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity